# Sending email using php, gmail, and swiftmailer causes SSL-related error 

Tags: php, email, ssl, gmail, swiftmailer

Here is my PHP code:

```
function SendCookieToTheMail()
{
    require_once 'swift-mailer/lib/swift_required.php';
    //Create the Transport
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com')
      ->setPort(465)
      ->setEncryption('ssl')
      ->setUsername('007@gmail.com')
      ->setPassword('123')
      ;

    //Create the Mailer using your created Transport
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    //Create a message
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Test')
      ->setFrom(array('007@gmail.com' => 'From mr. 007'))
      ->setTo(array('007@gmail.com', '007@gmail.com' => 'To mr. 007'))
      ->setBody('Body')
      ;

    //Send the message
    $result = $mailer->send($message);

    /*
    You can alternatively use batchSend() to send the message

    $result = $mailer->batchSend($message);
    */ 
}
```

Here is the error:

`( ! ) Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?) in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\swift-mailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 233`

`( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? #44551400]' in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\swift-mailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 235`

`( ! ) Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? #44551400] in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\swift-mailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 235`

Where is the problem??

### Update:

I checked `phpinfo()` and it says:

```
OpenSSL support     disabled (install ext/openssl)
```

I referred to the links below, but I couldn't install ssl...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did your php support SSL ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php, and check http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php for reference.

Create a page with

```
phpinfo();
```

Is SSL enabled?

Answer (score 16):

i Was searching for a similar question and i found that you have to edit the php.ini file 
edit the following line

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

remove the semi colon and it will work fine

Hope that help any one else :)

Answer (score 2):

gmail need this in your config.yml

swiftmailer:
    encryption: tls

or replace your:
->setEncryption('ssl')
by
->setEncryption('tls')

and not ssl

Answer (score 1):

You should enable php_openssl module from php extensions. Just edit your *php.ini* file

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

in fact, I advice to use tls on port 25
test using the following syntax:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 25, 'tls')
    ->setUsername('007@gmail.com')
    ->setPassword('123');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure php to work with ssl

http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you have solved your issue, however for me line:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

did not exist in my php.ini (running XAMPP 1.7.7 on Win7),
so just go ahead and add it in the extensions section, remove semicolon from it and it should work.