# Swiftmailer config : send mail using gmail

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, swiftmailer

I can send email from my pc using swiftmailer, but mail not sending in server.

I'm using swiftmailer 5.0.1. Project details are,

1. A simple php project in netbeans
2. swiftmailer 5.0.1
3. twig 1.13.1

My code is

```
public function init() {
        $this->username = 'username@gmail.com'; 
        $this->password = 'password';
        $this->host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
        $this->port = 465;
        $this->from = 'username@gmail.com';
        $this->subject = 'Company - contact';
        $this->body_part_type = 'text/html';
    }

public function send_email($from_name_add, $to_add, $fullname, $email, $mobile, $content) {
            $this->init();
            $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($this->host, $this->port)
                    ->setUsername($this->username)
                    ->setPassword($this->password);

            $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

            $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
            $cid = $message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath('../public_html/pic/logo.png'));
            $this->body = $this->renderEmailTemplate('email', $fullname, $email, $mobile, $content, $cid);
            $message->setSubject($this->subject)
                    ->setFrom(array('username@gmail.com' => '' . $from_name_add))
                    ->setTo($to_add)
                    ->setContentType($this->body_part_type)
                    ->setBody($this->body);
            $result = $mailer->send($message);
            return $result;
        }
```

This code works FINE in my pc. But after upload this code/project to server, mail not sending. Error is,

```
    <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host ssl://smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]' in /home/am***/lib/Swift/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:259
Stack trace:
#0 /home/am***/lib/Swift/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php(64): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer-&gt;_establishSocketConnection()
#1 /home/am***/lib/Swift/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(115): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer-&gt;initialize(Array)
#2 /home/am***/lib/Swift/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(80): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport-&gt;start()
#3 /home/am***/controller/send_mail.php(54): Swift_Mailer-&gt;send(Object(Swift_Message))
#4 /home/am***/public_html/contact.php(43): send_mail-&gt;send_email('Am*** Inc', 'fe****@gma...', 'asdf', 'asdf@in.com', '111111111111', 'Testing mail')
#5 {main}
  thrown in <b>/home/am***/lib/Swift/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php</b> on line <b>259</b><br />
```

**HINT:** There is an allready running php symfony2 project in that server, this project can send mail successfully.

Here is the symfony2 code,

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject($sub)->setFrom($from)->setTo($to)->setContentType("text/html")
                ->setBody($this->renderView('FZAm***Bundle:Layout:mail.html.twig', array
                    ('name' => $this->fullname, 'mobile' => $this->mobile, 'email' => $this->email,
                    'content' => $this->content, 'time' => $this->sys_time, 'ip' => $userip,
                    'server_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ));
try {
            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
// catch and other follows.
```

Config details are,

```
mail_contact_from: username@gmail.com
  mail_contact_to:   username@gmail.com
  mail_contact_sub:   Contact info
```

I passed only this details and all settings are default. If any info needed please ask i'l post.

**Reason i'm changing from symfony2 project to this ordinary php+swift+twig is my hosting is only 100mb and i need to upload more images. But symfony2 occupy more space.**

Comment: this may be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46864725/4680523

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your live server is missing `OpenSSL`, so you need to enable it in order to get secure connections working (i.e. enable the `php_openssl` module). Also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846599/sending-email-using-php-gmail-and-swiftmailer-causes-ssl-related-error).

Comment: Please check the question, symfony2 code works. Is symfony2 code runs without OpenSSL? Then is it sending mail without gmail config.

Comment: symfony2 is built on PHP. You seem to have an issue with your PHP configuration - either OpenSSL is not enabled, or PHP on your host is configured not to talk to other servers

Answer (score 4):

After some search in google.

To send mail using gmail auth you need to use this code,

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('ssl://smtp.gmail.com', 465);
```

**This is the correct way to send mail.** This mail will be send by gmail.

---

### **PHP** use mail() to send just a mail,

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

This code sends a mail using php code.

Swiftmailer can also send a mail using this php mail() function,

Here is swift code.

```
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
// nothing inside ()
```

The problem in this mail is, gmail displays following message,

> This message may not have been sent by: username@gmail.com

*Sometimes this mail will go to spam.*